# clone vs copying Array in Java?

Tags: java, arrays, copy, clone

I have this bit of code, where I am making a copy of an array.
using `System.arraycopy` seems more verbose than `clone()`. but both give the same results. are there any advantages of one over the other?
here is the code:

```
import java.util.*;
public class CopyArrayandArrayList {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        //Array copying
    char[] copyFrom = { 'd', 'e', 'c', 'a', 'f', 'f', 'e'};
    char[] copyTo = new char[7];

    System.arraycopy(copyFrom, 0, copyTo, 0, 7);

    char[] copyThree = new char[7];
    copyThree=copyFrom.clone();
}
}
```

Comment: this article is related, but does not explain if system.arraycopy is a deep cloning. It DOES mention that clone create a shallow copy and the examples there illustrates it. but to know if system.arraycopy is deep cloning with an illustration would be useful for beginners in Java

Comment: System.arraycopy() does what it says in the Javadoc, nothing more, no deep copy.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The object you created with:

```
char[] copyThree = new char[7];
```

will be gc'd. The "final result" could be achieved with:

```
char[] copyThree = copyFrom.clone();
```

Using `System.arrayCopy`, `copyFrom` and `copyTo` need to meet certain requirements, like array types and size of the array.

Using the `clone` method, a new array will be created, with the same contents of the other array (same objects - the same reference, not different objects with same contents). Of course the array type should be the same.

Both ways copy references of the array contents. They not `clone` the objects:

```
Object[] array = new Object[] {
    new Object(),
    new Object(),
    new Object(),
    new Object()};
Object[] otherArray = new Object[array.length];
Object[] clonedArray = array.clone();

System.arraycopy(array, 0, otherArray, 0, array.length);

for (int ii=0; ii<array.length; ii++) {

    System.out.println(array[ii]+" : "+otherArray[ii]+" : "+clonedArray[ii]);

}
```

Provides:

```
java.lang.Object@1d256a73 : java.lang.Object@1d256a73 : java.lang.Object@1d256a73
java.lang.Object@36fb2f8 : java.lang.Object@36fb2f8 : java.lang.Object@36fb2f8
java.lang.Object@1a4eb98b : java.lang.Object@1a4eb98b : java.lang.Object@1a4eb98b
java.lang.Object@2677622b : java.lang.Object@2677622b : java.lang.Object@2677622b
```